# Integral involving hyperbolic functions in combination with polynomials

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

In a recent theoretical physics problem, I stumbled across two integrals that I thought look quite easy but it turned out that I can't solve them. I appreciate any hint on how to get to a solution :)

The two integrals are defined by the functions:

1. $f(z) = \frac{\left(\pi ^2-4 z^2\right) \text{sech}^2(z)}{\left(4 z^2+\pi ^2\right)^2}$
2. $g(z) = \frac{\text{sech}^2(z)}{4 z^2+\pi ^2}$

as

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z) \,dz $ and $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(z) \,dz$

[Plot of f(z) and g(z) within some range of z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3QSW.png)

Thanks in advance to y'all

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hmmm. But maybe for $g$: It may work to integrate $g$ over the rectangle with vertices $-R, R, \pi i+R, \pi i-R$ and solve it via residue theorem. Or maybe also a demi circle in the upper half complex plane with radius $R$. Then maybe as $R\rightarrow \infty$, only the real integral stays... . It's at least worth a try.

Comment: @Meowdog Didn't have time to try much on this one - needed the result for my master thesis and used numerical methods there to approximate it. The one thing that I tried before was to derive it from some known (beta) integrals - Atm I am indeed trying to solve it using contour integration. I just haven't finished the computation yet ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residue theorem is the standard technique for dealing with such integrals.  We have

$$ \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x)} = -\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{\left(x-(2k+1)\frac{\pi i}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(x+(2k+1)\frac{\pi i}{2}\right)^2} $$

and

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{(x-z)^2(4x^2+\pi^2)} = \frac{2}{(2z+i\pi)^2}$$
for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ in the upper half-plane. It follows that

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{(4x^2+\pi^2)\cosh^2(x)} = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{\pi^2(k+1)^2}=\frac{1}{6} $$
and the other integral can be tackled in a similar fashion:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{(\pi^2-4z^2)\,dz}{(\pi^2+4z^2)^2\cosh^2(z)}=\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}. $$

Comment: Thank you a lot! :)